# How can I select a specific column in a row using jQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am very new to jQuery and JavaScript.
I have a small question.
Let's say i have a HTML table like the following

```
<Table id="mytable">
 <tr id="element">
  <td>value</td>
  <td>text</td>
</tr>
</Table>
```

In the above example i know the row id and i want to change the value of the second column of the row with that particular id.

I need a result something like the following:

```
 <Table id="mytable">
 <tr id="element">
  <td>value</td>
  <td>ChangedText</td>
</tr>
</Table>
```

So my question is: how can I select the 2<sup>nd</sup> column of the first row with a given id in order to change the value?

Comment: do you want to select ALL the second columns of every row, or only the second column of the first (on nth) row?

Comment: @Yanick - OP was pretty clear: *"i know the row id and i want to change the value of the second column of the row with that particular id"*

Comment: @patric dw, but an answer was suggesting a selector to find all the second TD of every row, so just wanted to make sure. As you can see, my answer presume what the OP is suggesting...

Comment: @Yanick - Which answer is that?

Comment: @patrick dw, Gert G's answer is selecting all the 2nd TD of every row

Comment: @Yanick - No, @Gert is using the `#element` ID selector that is specific to the row with that ID, so the other rows will not be affected. The `td:nth-child(2)` in the selector must be a descendant of `#element`.

Answer (score 24):

```
$("#element td:nth-child(2)").text('ChangedText');
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYD4/).

Answer (score 17):

something like

```
$('#mytable tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').text('ChangedText');
```

will select the first row, second column (0 based) of the given element (TABLE). In your case, since you know the row id :

```
$('#mytable #element td:eq(1)').text('ChangedText');
```

or simply

```
$('#element td:eq(1)').text('ChangedText');
```

Comment: I like this one, because when I think of iterations I always see 0 based index. When 2 actually means the second item, I start looking over my shoulder thinking something bad is going to happen today.

Comment: This is why CSS is meant for designers (1, 2, 3, 4...) and JavaScript for programmers (0, 1, 2, 3...) :)

Comment: :) Yes, as a programmer primarily, I am extremely thankful for bootstrap!

Answer (score 2):

Gert's code is how I would have implemented what you are asking so I won't repost it. However since you are new to jquery/javascript, you might like this tool I use to make sure my selectors are working http://www.woods.iki.fi/interactive-jquery-tester.html.

Cheers, 
Joe